# withText in split ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm having an issue where if the `ActionItem` has both an icon and text and the `ActionBar` is split, it will only show the icon even if the `showAsAction="always|withText"`.

Is there a way to force the text to appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`withText` is a hint to the system. On width-constrained devices or configurations the system may choose to ignore it.

Comment: Right, but even if this is the only item in a split `ActionBar` (so it has the whole width of a 4.65 inch screen to itself) it's still not showing up.  And if there's no icon it will show the text.

Comment: That's correct. The number of items or their measured size does not factor into the system's decision to display text+icon at once. It is based entirely on the device configuration. (Screen size, orientation, etc.)

Comment: Is there ever a case where text+icon will show in a split `ActionBar`?

Comment: Not in current implementations, but that may not always hold true in the future. The action bar should usually be treated as a semantic construct - give it as much information about your app as you like and it will present it in a way that matches system conventions on the current device.

Comment: Great answer. Disappointing that it doesn't actually measure the available width.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently and as already answered by adamp, there is no way to force the text to appear with the "withText" option.

Actually this can be done with a custom view in the Actionbar as i.e. in The Google Calendar's Edit/Create Event Screen (Cancel and Save button in the action bar, both with text).

Check the Google Calendars source on how it is done

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar

there is a layout for the Actionbar custom View in

res/layout/edit_event_custom_actionbar.xml

please also check the related styles

this is applied to the Actionbar in the EditEventFragment class, method onCreateView

```
if (mUseCustomActionBar) {
     View actionBarButtons = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_event_custom_actionbar,
             new LinearLayout(mContext), false);
     View cancelActionView = actionBarButtons.findViewById(R.id.action_cancel);
     cancelActionView.setOnClickListener(mActionBarListener);
     View doneActionView = actionBarButtons.findViewById(R.id.action_done);
     doneActionView.setOnClickListener(mActionBarListener);

     mContext.getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarButtons);
 }
```

The event handlers are assigned there as well.

The Actionbar display option are set in the EditEventActivity class, onCreate method:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,                      
         ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME|
         ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

This is what I figured out so far. There is some additional configuration for other screen options (tablets) using the standard menu configuration for the actionbar, but using a similar layout, style and those two snippets in my own code, produced the expected result (actionbar item with text).

Hope this helps

Comment: I cannot open the link? I do not know Google Calendar is open source.