# Determine if action bar is split

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a `MapView` with an action bar powered by ActionBarSherlock. The action bar is both split (on "narrow" screens) and overlayed / semi-transparent (android:windowActionBarOverlay is true). More or less like the Google Maps app.

Now I would like to push views on top of the map, at the bottom of the screen still keeping it above the bottom action bar. My problem here is that I don't know the height of the bottom action bar. Frankly, I can't even find a way to know if it's drawn or not. `getHeight()` seems to return the height of the top action bar (or perhaps it's the height of both of them but I still don't know if the bottom action bar exists or not.

Please, tell me this information is right in front of my eyes!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock you can look for the boolean value abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow

Just create some static method where you can do

```
return ResourcesCompat.getResources_getBoolean(context,
                            R.bool.abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow);
```

you need to use the ResourcesCompat (from actionbarsherlock) class because pre 3.2 cant read folders with metrics (like values-sw480)

Comment: Will this still work in API 3.1 + ?  i.e. if ActionBarSherlock is actually using the native action bar?

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, appreciate it - hopefully will help other users.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. On phone devices in portrait mode the actionbar is split. So menu-items are in the top actionbar and the tabs in a second actionbar (tabbar) below. I just did not find any possible way to determine the height of the actionbar: to see what space is left on the screen before building my screen.

So I did an assumption:

- on small and normal screensize devices the actionbar is split in portrait mode
- on large screensize devices (like Nexus 7) the actionbar is also split in portrait mode
- on xlarge screensize devices (tablets) the actionbar is not split in portrait mode

So I distinguish the different screensizes and created a bool resource

```
<!-- res/values/booleans.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="is_split_actionbar">false</bool>
</resources>

<!-- res/values-small-port/booleans.xml
     res/values-normal-port/booleans.xml
     res/values-large-port/booleans.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="is_split_actionbar">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In the code I access the value like this:

```
Boolean isSplit = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_split_actionbar);
```

To get the actionbar height in the onCreateView() method:

```
TypedValue typedVal = new TypedValue();
getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, typedVal, true); // use android.R when not using ABS
int actionBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(typedVal.resourceId);
```

And double the height if the actionbar is split:

```
if(isSplit) 
    actionBarHeight = actionBarHeight * 2;
```

It is not an ideal solution, but for me this works.

Comment: Closest answer to a solution.

Comment: It seems to me that this assumption is based on a false premise: my action bar splits on a Nexus 4, but doesn't on a Nexus 7.

Comment: It is not split on Nexus 7 API 25 Android Studio emulator too.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom bar should match the height of the regular action bar. Thus, using `?android:attr/actionBarSize` (or in ActionBarSherlock's case `?attr/actionBarSize`) for the height in XML or `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.attr.actionBarSize)` in code should suffice.

*edit:*

Er, on a second read of your question it seems more focused on also determining whether or not the split action bar exists.

You may want to read these answers and the follow-up comments by Adam Powell, action bar guru:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280776/132047
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381191/132047

Comment: Yes, I also need to know if it exists at all. Anyway, I was told (by Roman I think) on Android Office Hours that this was simply not possible. At least not in an easy and straight forward way. Therefore, we are now experimenting with a single top action bar and mimic the bottom action bar with a regular view instead. This solves not only this issue but another one as well where we wanted to "force" some actions to the top action bar.