# Different drawables for split actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to provide a different drawable icon if menu items are pushed to the split actionbar? My split action bar color differs to much from the top bar and a single icon style is not as visually please as I would hope.

Comment: To be clear, you're interested in changing the icon for `MenuItems`, but only if and when they are placed into the split ActionBar?

Comment: Yes, two sets of drawables, one for top action bar and one for bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Drawables` that you want to use for split in `/res/drawable/` and put the others in `/res/drawable-w480dp`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LevelListDrawable` for the icons and set the level when the screen configuration changes (which means `Activity.onCreate()`is called.

- Create a drawable to be used in the icons with

  ```
  <level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/**your bitmap dark**" />
  <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/**your bitmap light**" />
  </level-list>
  ```
- Detect, if ActionBar is splitted or not. This part seems to be tricky. I'm using SherlockActionBar and there it works (up to todays Android Version) [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105473/determine-if-action-bar-is-split)
- To change one drawable, set on the corresponding `ActionBar.Tab` the level with `getIcon().setLevel()`. Note that you do not need to cast to `LevelListDrawable`. For whatever reason the level concept is implemented directly with the `Drawable` class.

Comment: This is not necessary. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In the appcompat library the split ActionBar is used in configurations other than large, land or sw480dp. If youre using the native ActionBar i guess you can skip the large configuration.

[image: split_action_bar_is_narrow]

Then, to provide alternative drawables you should define appropriate references in these values dirs, like:

In `values`:

```
<item name="action_search_drawable" type="drawable" format="reference">@drawable/ic_action_search_narrow</item>
```

In `values-w480dp`:

```
<item name="action_search_drawable" type="drawable" format="reference">@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
```

Then, in the menu configuration you should use this reference as the icon drawable.